# Slack bot can send messages to a channel but cannot read messages coming from a channel

Tags: python, api, slack, slack-api

I have the following code running. **It's successfully sending the "Hello World!"** after server startup. But when I try to catch a message sent from the channel, I cannot do that. app.message("hello") method is not listening to the channel. Could someone help me figure this out?

```
from slack_bolt import App
import slack

# Initializes the app
app = App(
    token="--",
    signing_secret="--")

client = slack.WebClient(token="--")
BOT_ID = client.api_call("auth.test")['user_id']

client.chat_postMessage(channel='#know_more', text="Hello World!")

# Respond to hello
@app.message("hello")
def say_hello(message, say):
    say("hi")

# List all users
@app.command("/list")
def list_users(ack, say, command):    
    ack()
    say("list users")

# Start your app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.start(port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 3000)))
```